# KeyError in Flask app with uploaded CSV and CSV in Heroku

Tags: python, html, pandas, flask, heroku

I did this web app in Flask with a friend and I had the following form to get X and Y for any kind of plot from an uploaded CSV. The code is below:

```
    <form action="{{url_for('plot')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="form-group"><label>Select X Axis</label><select class="form-control" name="x_axis" required>
                        <option value=""></option>
                        {% for column in cols %}
                        <option value="{{column|string}}">{{column}}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select></div>
                    <div class="form-group"><label>Select Y Axis</label><select class="form-control" name="y_axis" required>
                        <option value=""></option>
                        {% for column in cols %}
                        <option value="{{column|string}}">{{column}}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select></div>
<div class="form-group"><label>Plot Type</label><select class="form-control" name="plot_type" required>
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="scatter">Scatter Plot</option>
                        <option value="line">Line Plot</option>
                        <option value="bar">Bar Plot</option>
                        <option value="sunburst">Sunburst Plot</option>
                        <option value="corelation">Correlation Matrix</option>
                        <option value="table">Table</option>
                    </select><br><br>
                    <div class="form-group"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Plot</button></div>
                </form>
```

The previous page is to upload the CSV and we get the column names from that for these options.
I get a KeyError for any column when hitting submit but it works fine locally.
Almost like

> KeyError: "Column"

I have tried removing the string in {{column|string}} to no avail.

Areas where I feel the error can be:

1. Saving the CSV
   I save the CSV with the following code:

```
def plot_choose():
    f = request.files['csv']
    if f.filename.split('.')[1] == 'csv':
        f.save(secure_filename(f.filename))
    else:
        return "<h1>Incorrect File Format</h1>"
    global df
    df = pd.read_csv(f.filename)
    df = df.dropna(how = "any")

    return render_template('plot.html', cols=list(df.columns), tables = [df.head().to_html(classes='data')])
```

I declared df at the start as just pd.Dataframe({}) and called global here. The error existed however even without doing this bit actually.

2. The form code
   I mentioned the form code earlier. I think maybe the frontend is not passing the column name properly I don't know.
3. The code to get columns
   The code to get the columns from the form is below:

```
x_ax = str(request.form['x_axis'])
y_ax = str(request.form['y_axis'])
plot = str(request.form['plot_type'])
```

The funny thing here is that it results in the same error even with a CSV that is stored in the server too.

Any other clarifications, I will be happy to address.

Comment: Are you sure you're not dropping all data: `df = df.dropna(how = "any")`?

Comment: No, not at all. I ran through the same code in a Jupyter Notebook and it was good. I think it may be a Heroku problem since I managed to host it in PythonAnywhere and the error didn't pop up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept trying to use it in Heroku but it was of no use. I switched to PythonAnywhere and now the error does not pop up.